# How to update single item in recyclerview from json?

Tags: java, android, json, database

- I need to update elements like this image
- I fetch data from JSON URL
- I need a way to do something like in the image

[image: gif]

Answer (score 0):

Once you have mapped the object from the JSON, you have to update the item of the list and finally call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify the changes. Depending of the feature that you want, you have to start another thread to update the score in real time or simple trigger the update with a button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update specific items and not the whole list you should use adapter.notifyItemChanged(). The easiest way is to update the list that you have given to the adapter to display, then notify the adapter that items have been changed with notifyItemChanged(index), where index is the position of your updated item in the list.

For even more granularity you can use notifyItemChanged(index, payload) which you can set up to update only a part of the updated item, where payload is used in your onBindViewHolder() to "mark" what has changed.

Comment: i'm sorry, are you have any samples?